# Python Use Dictionary List? What Do I Use

Tags: python

I am making a type of quiz, and want to know how to compare the results to a text file. After answering the questions with prompted input, the function will return a four digit code. I want that four digit code to be compared to "truecode" in a text file I've written out with additional information like this:

```
villagername,personality,birthday,zodiac,truecode,species
Ankha,snooty,September 22nd,Virgo,A420,Cat
Bangle,peppy,August 27th,Virgo,A330,Tiger
Bianca,peppy,December 13th,Sagittarius,A320,Tiger
Bob,lazy,January 1st,Capricorn,A210,Cat
Bud,jock,August 8th,Leo,A310,Lion
```

I want this other information to be printed out.

```
    print("Your villager is " + villagername)
    print("They are a " + personality + " type villagers and of the " + species + " species.")
    print("Their birthday is " + birthday + " and they are a " + zodiac)
    print("I hope you enjoyed this quiz!")
```

I cannot figure out how to extract this information and compare it to what I have. Should I use a list or a dictionary? I'm getting frustrated trying to Google my question and wondering if I went around it all wrong.

How do I compare the four digit code (that will be returned from another function) to "true code" and get everything spit out like above?

Answer (score 0):

The type of file that you have is actually called a CSV file. If you wanted to, you could open your text file with any spreadsheet program, and your data would show up in the appropriate cells. Use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read your data.

```
import csv

def get_quiz_results(truecode):
    with open('your-text-file.txt') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            # row is a dictionary of all of the items in that row of your text file.
            if row['truecode'] == truecode:
                return row
```

And then to print out the info from your text file

```
truecode = 'A330'
info = get_quiz_results(truecode)
print("Your villager is " + info["villagername"])
print("They are a " + info["personality"] + " type villagers and of the " + info["species"] + " species.")
print("Their birthday is " + info["birthday"] + " and they are a " + info["zodiac"])
print("I hope you enjoyed this quiz!")
```

When looping over the file, the csv module will turn each line of the file into a dictionary using the commas as separators. The first line is special, and is used to create the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
def compare_codes(true_code):
    with open(''file.txt) as csvfile:
        details_dict = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for i in details_dict:
        if i['truecode'] == tru_code:
           print("Your villager is:",i['villagername'])
           print("They are a " + i['personality'] + " type villagers and of the " + i['species'] + " species.")
           print("Their birthday is " + i['birthday'] + " and they are a " + i['zodiac'])
           print("I hope you enjoyed this quiz!")
           break

compare_codes('A420')
```

Above code reads the text file and compares the input with truecode value in your file and displays the info.

Comment: Even though your answer should be valid, I think the same result can be achieved without using such a powerful library as pandas. Built-in `csv` module is more than enough for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv


def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        data = {row['truecode']: row for row in reader}

    return data


def main():
    filename = 'results.txt'
    data = get_data(filename)

    code = input('Enter code: ')

    try:
        info = data[code]
        print("Your villager is " + info['villagername'])
        print("They are a " + info['personality'] +
              " type villagers and of the " + info['species'] + " species.")
        print("Their birthday is " +
              info['birthday'] + " and they are a " + info['zodiac'])
        print("I hope you enjoyed this quiz!")

    except KeyError:
        print('Invalid code')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```